# Understanding/reporting model checks for binomial GLM's - what are the model checks telling me?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

I have two binomial GLM's, one of which has passed model checks and the other has not. I have checked the model fits by extracting resids and examined their distributions in  histograms. Observations with a deviance residual in excess of >2.0 indicates a lack of fit. Secondly, I have done a binned plot to check that 95% of resids fall within the grey lines indicating +/- 2SE.

Although I can interpret these graphs I'm not sure what they are actually telling me? I'm trying to explain in my methods the above model checks I carried out but I'm struggling to write about it as I'm not sure what I'm 'checking' or what the model that did pass the checks is actually 'passing?' Any help would be really appreciated!

Why exactly have I done these checks and what are they telling me?

Answer (score 0):

Quantification of "when to worry" about deviance and other residuals when Y is binary is less well established than you might think.  And looking at such general assessments of goodness of fit doesn't lead to a clear corrective action.  For those reasons, it is more fruitful to postulate the most flexible model that your effective sample size will support, and to fit that model.  If it doesn't fit well enough there's not much you can do about it anyway, so this is a pragmatic solution.  The fit is made flexible by not assuming linearity and additivity, by incorporation of regression spline and interaction terms.

In general, goodness of fit IMHO is best assessed by directed tests (although testing may make you change the model and that will distort inference).  An example of a directed test is testing nonlinear spline terms to assess nonlinearity of a variable's effect on, say, the log odds scale.  [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms) covers the suggested approach in detail.

Comment: thanks for you response but I'm not sure it has answered my original question.. if anything I think it may have confused me more

Comment: Convert the approach to specific directed tests e.g. non-linear and interaction effects.